# C# ItextSharp multiple PDFStampers to one output file

Tags: c#, itext

I have a requirement where I have multiple PDF files in a folder, I want to read them all file by file, do some manipulation to each file and output them into one output file. I can get the code to work for each individual file, the errors come when i try and output it into a singular output pdf. I've tried numerous ways of achieving this and my most recent test has the error

```
iTextSharp.text.DocumentException: 'The original document was reused. Read it again from file.'
```

Here is my current code

```
PdfStamper stamper = null;
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Temp\Output.pdf", FileMode.Create))
using (Document doc = new Document())
using (PdfCopy pdf = new PdfCopy(doc, fs))
 {
  doc.Open();
  foreach (var testfile in new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Temp\Input\").GetFiles("*.pdf"))
   {
    using (var reader = new PdfReader(testfile.FullName))
     {

       for (int x = 1; x <= reader.NumberOfPages; x++)
        {
         PdfImportedPage page = null;
         page = pdf.GetImportedPage(reader, x );
         pdf.AddPage(page);
         var xfer = ConvertToPoint(Convert.ToDouble(10));
         var yfer = ConvertToPoint(Convert.ToDouble(280));
         var uxfer = ConvertToPoint(Convert.ToDouble(80));
         var uyfer = ConvertToPoint(Convert.ToDouble(230));
         RenderFilter[] filters = new RenderFilter[1];
         LocationTextExtractionStrategy regionFilter = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
         filters[0] = new RegionTextRenderFilter(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle((float)xfer, (float)yfer, (float)uxfer, (float)uyfer));
         ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new FilteredTextRenderListener(new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(), filters);
         String result = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, x, strategy);

         var rect = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle((float)xfer, (float)yfer, (float)uxfer, (float)uyfer);
         rect.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.LEFT_BORDER | iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.RIGHT_BORDER | iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.TOP_BORDER | iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER;
         rect.BorderWidth = 2;
         rect.BorderColor = iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.WHITE;
         rect.BackgroundColor = iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.WHITE;
         using (stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fs))
          {
           stamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;
           int PageCount = reader.NumberOfPages;
           PdfContentByte cb = stamper.GetOverContent(x);
           cb.Rectangle(rect);
           cb.BeginText();
           var baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);

           cb.SetFontAndSize(baseFont, 12);
           var start = 266;
           foreach (var split in result.Split('\n'))
            {
             cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, split, ConvertIntToPoint(24), (float)ConvertToPoint((double)start), 0);
             start = start - 4;

            }
           cb.EndText();


          }
         }

        }
      }
     }
```

Comment: You have one `PdfCopy` and multiple `PdfStamper` instances writing to the same `FileStream fs`.  This makes your result file a hodgepodge of all the outputs of those objects. Either first stamp all source files storing them separately and then merge them in a second step or use `PageStamp`s.